# This logger has no handler, yet it prints. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a sample logger that I think has no handler, yet it outputs log messages.  Here is the code:

```
import logging

ll = logging.getLogger('ll')
print("Has handlers:", ll.hasHandlers())
print("Handlers:", ll.handlers)
ll.propagate = False

ll.warning("Logging with no Handler!")
```

And the result says the logger has no handlers, there is an empty list of handlers, yet it prints the output:

```
%  python example.py
Has handlers: False
Handlers: []
Logging with no Handler!
%
```

Why does this work?  Do I need to add a `NullHandler()` to stop output?

Comment: I believe that the default configuration of the root logger will print out warns and above. Consider calling [`logging.basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig).

Comment: Yes. I assumed that this would work as I see it if I *had* called `logging.basicConfig`.  I'm just surprised it works without it.

Comment: I think setting `propagate` to `False` only applies to messages that are handled locally. Without a specific handler, it will always be passed up to a parent's handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because for Python >= 3.2, there is a [*handler of last resort*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.lastResort) which outputs events of severity `WARNING` and greater to `sys.stderr`.